# Get Count of ALL Records (All Objects) in Recycling Bin

Tags: soql

Looking for a SOQL query (or some other method) to get a count of records in my orgs recyclying bin. I have seen other solutions posted suggesting to use the IsDeleted = TRUE and ALL ROWS to the SOQL statement, but these all involve querying a specific object (i.e. FROM Account). I need a count of ALL records in the recycling bin. Thanks if possible.

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to query records from different subject types. Therefore the [database class](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_database.htm) implements several methods to delete "specific" records.

**Potential solution**

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> globalDescription = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Integer counter = 0;
for(String key : globalDescription.keyset())
{
    counter += Database.getDeleted(key, DateTime.now().addYears(-1), DateTime.now()).getDeletedRecords().size();
}
```

I'm not 100% sure but it looks like there is no [limit](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm) for `Database.getDeleted`method calls.